# using variables in search pattern in awk script

Tags: shell, awk

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f  `

{  
awkvar2="/id=22/";  
awkvar3="/end/";  


if ($0 ~ awkvar2) {  
    triggered=1;  
  }  
  if (triggered) {  
     print;  
     if ($0 ~ awkvar3) {  
        triggered=0;  
        print "\n-----------------------------------------------\n"  
     }  
  }  
}
```

this awk script is not working for me
i am trying to search from one line to another i.e `id=22` till `end`
(the reason i am not using `/<string>/,/<string>/` is because i want a big line after each block of search)
and i want this using variables only.
i could directly use the patterns `if ($0 ~ /end/) {`
but i dont want to do that, i want to use the variables inside the search pattern
(reason is i will be getting the values in the variables dynamically thorough the shell)

please advise me how to use variables inside the search pattern for awk

thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
awkvar2="id=22";
awkvar3="end"; 
if ($0 ~ awkvar2) {
        triggered=1;
         }
if (triggered) {
         print;
         if ($0 ~ awkvar3) {
              triggered=0;
              print "\n-----------------------------------------------\n"
         }
}
}
```

**Edit**

Modified per request to print the line before "id=22"

```
{
  awkvar2="id=22";
  awkvar3="end"; 
  if ($0 ~ awkvar2) {
          print prev;
          triggered=1;
  }
  if (triggered) {
          print;
          if ($0 ~ awkvar3) {
              triggered=0;
              print "\n-----------------------------------------------\n"
          }
  }
  {prev=$0;}
}
```

Or, more *awkish*

```
BEGIN {awkvar2="id=22";awkvar3="end"}

($0 ~ awkvar2),($0 ~ awkvar3) { if ($0 ~ awkvar2) {print prev;}
                                print; 
                                if ($0 ~ awkvar3) {
                                    print "\n---------------\n"
                                }
                               }
{prev=$0;}
```

Comment: how do i print the line before `id=22` for above script

Comment: @Omkar Updated. Please remember to accept and eventually upvote your preferred answers in stack overflow.

Comment: smart!! storing the previous line in a variable and then printing it

Comment: i actually wanted to print 2 lines so i simply extentded your idea 
{
   prev2 = prev; 
   prev=$0;
}

Comment: sorry, i hadnt clicked accepted, now i did,  but what do u mean by upvote?

Comment: @Omkar You may also try something like {prev[i++ % 2] = $0} and then { print prev[(i-1)%2] ; print prev[i%2] }

Comment: @Omkar At the answer heading you'll see two grey triangles, one for vote up and the other for down. The answers and questions that you think are helpful may deserve up-voting. When in doubt, read the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Omkar In fact you'll see a number "1"  between the two triangles in this answer. That means that someone else upvoted it, because he/she considered it useful. If you vote it, you'll see the number changing to "2". Accepting is different, and can be done only by the original poster (you)

Comment: @Omkar: You can also accumulate previous lines: `prev = prev "\n" $0` and when you print (or otherwise process) `prev` you'll need to clear it: `prev = ""`. This is scalable without having to add multiple variables.

Comment: @Omkar: As an alternative to using `BEGIN` to set the variables, if you want to set them from the command line without editing the code or set them to a value in a shell variable, use `-v`: `awk -v awkvar2="id=22" -v awkvar3="$shellvar" '{ ... }'`

Comment: @Dennis .... but thinking again he only needs 2 lines before the start regexp match ...

Comment: For the specific case it's sufficient. I just offered a way to generalize it.

Comment: thanks Dennis and belisarius for your valuable inputs
@Dennis - coincidentally, i later changed my code to exactly what u said and i will be using similar logic to print next few lines too. Also about ur next comment, i had mentioned in my post `(reason is i will be getting the values in the variables dynamically through the shell)`, so yes, i am already getting the variables from the shell using -v

Comment: Even more awkish?

    `BEGIN {awkvar2="id=22";awkvar3="end"}
    
    ($0 ~ awkvar2) {print prev;}
    ($0 ~ awkvar2),($0 ~ awkvar3) {print; }
    ($0 ~ awkvar3) {print "\n---------------\n"}
                   {prev=$0;}`

Answer (score 0):

More compact version of belisarius awk script, without 'if's

```
BEGIN {awkvar2="id=22";awkvar3="end"}

($0 ~ awkvar2) {print prev;}
($0 ~ awkvar2),($0 ~ awkvar3) {print; }
($0 ~ awkvar3) {print "\n---------------\n"}
               {prev=$0;}
```