# Does /flt/ substitute variable 'flt' in awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

22 content:

```
/dev/sda3            236235512  97617352 126618008  44% /
/devtmpfs               8388608        92   8388516   1% /dev
/dev/sda1              2063504     97580   1861104   5% /boot
```

---

For scripts 1-4, the result is: `/devtmpfs 8388608 92 8388516 1% /dev`,
but script 5 gives no output.

1. `awk -F"[ ]+"  "{if(\$6 ~ /dev/) print \$0}" 22`
2. `flt=dev ; awk -F"[ ]+"  "{if(\$6 ~ /$flt/) print \$0}" 22`
3. `awk -F"[ ]+"  '{if($6 ~ flt) print $0}' flt=dev 22`
4. `awk -F"[ ]+"  '{if($6 ~ /dev/) print $0}' 22`
5. `awk -F"[ ]+"  **'{if($6 ~ /flt/)** print $0}' flt=dev 22`

Does the `/flt/` in the last example substitute variable 'flt' into the regular expression?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: You got your answer but you have multiple issues in every script you posted above so if you plan to use awk I suggest you post your attempt here and ask for feedback first as you have some basic misunderstandings about awk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using variables in search pattern in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266770/using-variables-in-search-pattern-in-awk-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/flt/` means a match with the regular expression `flt`, which is not present in your input file, so there is no match..